# MySQL: carriage-return in query

Tags: mysql, carriage-return

I have a query that exports data from two columns of each row into a file. In the file data from each column should be separated by carriage-return, something like this:

row1column1
row1column2
row2column1
row2column2
row3column1
row3column2

I tried using char(13):

```
SELECT CONCAT(column1, char(13), column2) FROM my_table INTO outfile 'my_file'
```

and the output file seemed perfectly fine (each column data was in another line), but when I used it as input to a program that should accept described format, it didn't recognize it. However, when I manually erased all carriage-returns in the file and added them again by pressing "enter" key, my program recognized the file without a problem.
When I tried with char(13), char(10), my output file looked like this:

row1column1
\
row1column2
row2column1
\
row2column1

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here :)

Comment: what the format of file output 
, csv file ?

Answer (score 8):

i see it in mysql site, hope its help u.

> You should use the following syntax to
>   create a CSV file in the format
>   expected by Microsoft Excel:
>
> ... INTO OUTFILE '/temp.csv' FIELDS
>   ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ','
>   ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY
>   '\r\n';
>
> However fields with carriage returns
>   may break the CSV as MySQL will
>   automatically close a field when the
>   \r\n line break is found. To work
>   around this, replace all \r\n breaks
>   with \n. The field does not close on
>   \n breaks and it will be read into a
>   single cell in Excel. You can do this
>   in the same SQL statement, for
>   example:
>
> SELECT REPLACE(field_with_line_breaks,
>   '\r\n', '\n') FROM table INTO OUTFILE
>   '/temp.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""'
>   TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
>
> I also found that null values could
>   break the CSV. These can be handled in
>   a similar way:
>
> SELECT IFNULL(possible_null_field, "")
>   FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/temp.csv'
>   FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY
>   ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED
>   BY '\r\n';
>
> Note: this replaces NULL values with
>   an empty string which is technically
>   not the same thing but it will give
>   you an empty cell in Excel instead of
>   breaking the CSV structure and
>   shifting the following cells to the
>   left.

Answer (score 7):

Haim Evgi's answer works, but:

```
SELECT REPLACE(field_with_line_breaks, '\r\n', '\n') FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/temp.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I had to change to:

```
SELECT REPLACE(field_with_line_breaks, '\r\n', '\n') FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/temp.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

There was a double quote in the FIELDS ESCAPED BY, which gave this error in mysql: "Error 1083: Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual".

Changing it to a single quote stopped the error and exported a file. I was able to then import it into excel successfully with the newlines formatted correctly.

Comment: I think you should've just edited Haim Evgi's answer. I did that; it's not yet approved.

Answer (score 4):

Try just char(10) - that's "\n" - the UNIX way.
Just char(13) "\r" is the (old) mac way and "\r\n" is the windows way, but I suspect MySQL just uses \n for each row, so you'll need to match that.

Comment: That just puts "\" between two columns

Comment: Note that to get the query to work on the CLI (mysql -Ne) I had to use -r Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch. HTH, Dan.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have problems with differences in interpretation of newline between operating systems.

If your MySQL database is on Unix/Linux, and a file will be read on Unix or database is on Windows and will be read on Windows then try this:

```
select * into outfile 'my_file'
fields terminated by '\n' lines terminated by '\n'
from my_table;
```

If your MySQL database is on Unix/Linux, and a file will be read on Windows then try this:

```
select * into outfile 'my_file'
fields terminated by '\r\n' lines terminated by '\r\n'
from my_table;
```

You can also convert a file between "CRLF" (Windows) and "LF" (Unix) newlines using a small, command line utility called dos2unix and unix2dos, which is included in most Linux distributions.